# Can a method in Java use variables declared earlier in the class without having to pass them as parameters?

Tags: java

for instance would this be valid?

```
public void backtrack()
    {
     char d = "d";//initialize a series of characters to represent looked for directions
     char l = "l";
     char t = "t";
     char temp = " ";//not sure why i put this here

     String j = DNA1;// create two strings to be used for indexing purposes 
     String k = DNA2;

     int x = mat_hold[0].length;//goes to the last row
     int e = mat_hold.length;//goes to the last column
     char[][] mat_hold2 = mat_hold;
     opt_path = mat_hold[x][e];//initialize the beginning of the path to be last element in the array

     while(opt_path != mat_hold2[0][0];)//while the current index does not equal the first element in the array
        {
         if(opt_path = d)// if the element in d was obtained from the diagonal
            {
             DNA_seq1.insert(0,j[x]);//using the matrix location [x][e]take the element from the DNA sequence and insert it into the front of the array we are building
             DNA_seq2.insert(0,k[e]);//ditto
             DNA_align.insert(0,"|");//since they are the same in this case, insert a line to connect them
             opt_path = mat_hold[x-1][e-1]//set the opt path to the diagonal value to be searched
            }//since in this case it was taken from the diagonal, that means both letters were the same and so both letters at the given
            //indexes are inserted into the newly constructed sequence
         if(opt_path = l)
            {
             DNA_seq1.insert(0,"_");
             DNA_seq2.insert(0,k[e]);
             DNA_align.insert(0," ");
             opt_path = mat_hold[x][e-1];
            }
         if(opt_path = t)
            {
             DNA_seq1.insert(0,j[x]);
             DNA_seq2.insert(0,"_");
             DNA_align.insert(0," ");
             opt_path = mat_hold[x-1][e];
            }
        }
    }
```

where DNA1, DNA2, Dna_seq1, Dna_seq2, mat_hold etc are all declared and constructed earlier in the class definition. or would i have to write all of these into the parameters being passed?

Comment: Within an instance method you use both instance and static fields.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? It's not a complicated issue, and you are able to find if you can do it or you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Use [fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) instead of local variables. Something like that:

```
public class YourClassName {

    private static final String DNA_seq2 = null;
    private Object DNA_seq1;
    private Object DNA_align;
    private char[][] mat_hold;

    public void backtrack() {
        char d = 'd';//initialize a series of characters to represent looked for directions
        char l = 'l';
        char t = 't';
        char temp = ' ';//not sure why i put this here
        // Rest of your method...
    }
}
```

Actually, the definition order is irrelevant. Fields are available in any place of your class, regardless of where they are declared:

```
public class YourClassName {

    public void backtrack() {
        char d = 'd';//initialize a series of characters to represent looked for directions
        char l = 'l';
        char t = 't';
        char temp = ' ';//not sure why i put this here
        // Rest of your method... and it can use DNA_seq2, too, although
        // it is declared below.
    }

    private static final String DNA_seq2 = null;
    private Object DNA_seq1;
    private Object DNA_align;
    private char[][] mat_hold;
}
```

The order is relevant only for local variables.

However, it is surely the smallest of your problems if this code you posted is the real one you have...

Comment: thank you, and yes i realize i have a lot to clean up when i try to initialize this.